# How to set LayoutParams for ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, layoutparams

I'm new to Android. In my app I have created an ImageView programmatically in my `FrameLayoutProgramatically` class but when I use `setLayoutParams` 
of this Imageview there it's showing errors. Why am I getting these errors?

My `FrameLayoutProgramatically` class:

```
public class FrameLayoutProgramatically extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Initializing imageView
        ImageView imageview = new ImageView(this);
        imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.nature);
        imageview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}
```

Comment: this line showing eroors when i types imageview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

Comment: do i have to import anything extra in my class?

Comment: so what is your parent layout in xml linear or relative??

Comment: i want to create programatically everthing i don't want to use xml here

Comment: ok wait i will post the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You need to specify which **LayoutParams** you need to use, it must be
>   based on parent layout which can be anything
>   **LinearLayout.LayoutParams** or **RelativeLayout.LayoutParams** or **FrameLayout.LayoutParams**.

```
RelativeLayout imageLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

ImageView imageview = new ImageView(this);
imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.nature);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

imageLayout.addView(iv, lp);
```

or

```
imageview.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
imageLayout.addView(iv);
```

Comment: i am adding this fields on Framelayout

Comment: FrameLayouts are designed to only hold one View, so this isn't really the appropriate choice. but you can add this relative layout to you framelayout

Comment: see that link there we can create framelayout programatically i am exactly following this

Comment: then try to use FrameLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: then how can we cretae framelayout programatically i mean this line  framelayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
       LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

Comment: FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(this);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106075/discussion-between-abhiram-and-madhur).